# Send package name to any market

Tags: android, android-intent

i know there are some topics with this title. but all of them only works with GooglePlay.
i want to let users choose their favorite market. send package name to market and get results.

i also tested this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```

but this is not supported by some markets.

Comment: "market://" launce play store app only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate intent for Amazon Appstore and Google Play:

This bit of code figures out which store it was installed from, then tries Google Play and Amazon Appstore. If the intents fail, it falls back to the right web page

```
String installer = getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName());
if ("com.amazon.venezia".equals(installer)) {

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("amzn://apps/android?p=com.monadpad...."));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com..."));
        startActivity(browser);
    }


}
else if ("com.android.vending".equals(installer)) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.monadpad..."));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.monadpad...."));
        startActivity(browser);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is very good solution , but is there a way to show popup menu and user choose the market?

Comment: I do that manually. I place the Amazon and Google Play buttons next to each other. If the Installer Package is one or the other, I hide the other one. I can also test getLaunchIntentForPackage() to see if the Google Play app and Amazon Appstore apps are installed. On a NOOK, for example, neither will be installed. NOOK's is this if you need it: https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/20107613-cross-linking-to-your-other-apps-in-the-shop